# Illegal start of type error when compiling

Tags: java

Am writing a program which allows two superheros to fight. However when I try to compile the I get an illegal start type error.

```
public class Fight {

    public static void main(String [] args); {
        Superhero Spiderman = new Superhero();
        Superhero TheHumanTorch = new Superhero(21);
    }

    public Spiderman fight(TheHumanTorch opponet); {
        System.out.Println(TheHumanTorch);
    }

    private void powerUp(100); {
        Spiderman Strength = Srength + 100;
    }

    public Spiderman fight(TheHumanTorch opponet); {
        System.out.Println(Spiderman);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Superhero {

    public String Name;
    private int Strength;

    public Superhero(String n, int s) {

        Name = n;
        Strength = s;

    }

    public Superhero(String n) {

        Name = n;
        Strength = 10;
    }

    private void powerUp(int powerUp) {
        Srength = Srength + powerUp;
    }

}

    public Superhero fight(Superhero opponet) {
        if (this.Strength > opponet.Strength) {
            return this;
        } else {
            return opponet;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (this.Stength) {
            return "Superhero";
        } else {
            return "Superhero opponet";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your query and show in which line you get the error

Comment: Please edit your post to format your code properly. It's *very* hard to read at the moment. You also have syntax errors such as `public Spiderman fight(TheHumanTorch opponet); {` - I think you're confused between types and variables apart from anything else. I suggest you reread whatever Java book/tutorial you're using very carefully... Stack Overflow isn't good for helping with fundamental ideas like that.

Comment: Could you give us the exact error message that you received, please?

Comment: You should decide whether `Spiderman` and `TheHumanTorch` are variables or classes. You seem to use them as both.

Comment: Fight.java:15 error: illegal start of type

Comment: You also have an extra end-brace after `powerUp`

Comment: @Andreas yeah, but ultimately it's up to the persons style. As long as it is consistent, it is fine. In this code it is not.

Answer (score 1):

It is being caused by this code:

```
private void powerUp(100); {
    Spiderman Strength = Srength + 100;
}
```

You need to provide the type and parameter name to the method. I'm guessing you meant to provide something like `amount` to it. Something like this *could* compile if a class named `Spiderman` was available and `Srength` was available to the scope of this method:

```
private void powerUp(int amount) {
    Spiderman Strength = Srength + amount;
}
```

Another issue is that you have too many brackets in your class definition:

```
    private void powerUp(int powerUp) {
        Srength = Srength + powerUp;
    }

}
// This is the closing bracket for the class definition.
```

You should remove that extra bracket. Your code below is not being included in the class definition.

There are plenty of other issues, as well. When you try to compile, the compiler will help you discover these problems and give you context as to how to fix them.

You seem like you may be new to programming, so you may just be using an editor like Notepad or VI. A lot of developers (most) use a tool called an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), which makes a developer's life *much* better. A few examples would be:

- [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/)
- [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/)

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) mentioned, your `main` and other methods have semicolons when they should not:

```
public static void main(String [] args); {
```

Should be:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
```

There are *plenty* of other issues that your compiler (or IDE) will catch that you will need to address, too. Here are a just a few examples your compiler will find, that you will have to figure out how to fix:

- `Spiderman` isn't a defined class
- `TheHumanTorch` isn't a defined class
- `Println` isn't a method defined on `java.io.PrintStream` (your `System.out.Println` call)
- `Srength` and `Stength` will not be resolved. You probably mean `Strength`

I recommend that you slowly iterate over your code with a Java resource nearby to help guide you through some examples and compare what you wrote vs. how the examples are written.

Comment: That, and the semicolons in lines like `public static void main(String [] args); {`

Comment: @Andreas Good catch. Now that I am looking at it more, there are even more issues than that...

Comment: Thanks goes to Jon Skeet. I was just plagiarizing his comment to question.

Comment: Instead of "the compiler should really help", I'd suggest that you suggest to use an IDE. Writing Java without an IDE is ludicrous.